# My Exomedia code is not working in some devices, how can i fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, live-streaming

I'm creating a live streaming (that uses exomedia), with admin panel but i dont know in some devices the live stream does not open its stays black no mediaplayer controls nothing shows up just a black page, in other devices it works fine, live stream starts as it should, the mediaplayer control shows up, (I tried this in two Samsung s8 phones, in one phone it worked just fine, in a other phone it stays black.

i have done some test in in android api24(Android 7.0) is working just fine in api28(Android 9) the channel does not play it stays black and nothing shows up

JAVA

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_streaming);

    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

}

@Override
public void onPrepared() {
    //Starts the video playback as soon as it is ready
    videoView.start();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

public void closeStreaming() {
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - exitTime) > 2000) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.press_again_to_close_streaming), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

}